# How did this 1 rep user get the Custodian badge?

Tags: bug, review-queues, reputation, badges

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9033988/subarna?tab=profile) seems to have got 2k rep at some point, since they have got the Custodian badge for reviewing suggested edits:

[image: Badge awarded]

However, they currently only have 1 rep, and they never had 2k according to their reputation page. This is their entire reputation change history:

[image: reputation history]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18814728

Comment: I didn't realise that you could

Comment: You can also reject an edit on your own post even after two other reviewers approve it.

Comment: @BSMP Ok, I didn't kow

Comment: @gnat Yes, I can't seem to accept that from mobile.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

User approved a suggested edit on their own question

Review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18814728

Comment: Oh. Didn't realise you could.