# How to find suggested edits on my posts if I don't have 2k reputation?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, reputation

According to [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366019/how-did-this-1-rep-user-get-the-custodian-badge), I can reject or approve suggested edits on my own questions even if I don't have enough reputation. How can I do that?

I don't have 2000 reputation so when I go to the [suggested edits page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), it says "**You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits.**". Where can I find suggestions on my posts and how can I be noticed when there is a new suggestion?

Comment: You will get a notification if someone suggests an edit to your post.

Comment: @Abdul from there I can accept or reject it?

Comment: Yes, if you click the notification you will be taken to the suggested edits queue (you will only be shown edits to your own posts) and you can accept / reject, etc the edit.

Comment: However, you should be aware that users are not notified for *every* edit which is made to one of their posts. The edit needs to be "substantive". In the case of edits to posts, "substantive" is as described [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post/202415#202415).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you missed/ignored the notification in your inbox, you can visit the Responses tab in your profile, which has a [Revisions section](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=revisions) showing all past revisions on your posts.

[image: profile with tabs Summary, Answers, Questions etc where Responses is highlighted, right side of the screen has sub-tans with all, Revision (highlighthed), Comments, Answers]

If you want to look for pending suggested edits on other users posts (without having access to the review queue) use the Stack API endpoint[`/suggested-edits`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits#fromdate=2021-05-11&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)